# I can't seem to get tkMessageBox.askokcancel in Python 2.7 to get to work

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I have written the following code

```
    closeButton = Button(self, text="Close",command=self.askyesno)
    closeButton.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
    okButton = Button(self, text="OK")
    okButton.pack(side=RIGHT)

def askyesno():
    res = tkMessageBox.askokcancel(title="Quit", message="Do you want to quit?")
    if res == "yes":
    self.quit()
```

Whenever I press the close button, python crashes
with the message
Type error: askyesno() takes no arguments, 1 given.
There are many examples on the Internet like mine. I'm sure they work. What am I doing wrong. All the examples I found have this problem and the documentation for tkMessageBox is not providing any examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the tkMessageBox, it's your function. You  should define it like this:

```
#def askyesno():    # Not like this
def askyesno(self):
```

Assuming it's a member of a class.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I also noticed that I shouldn't use tkMessageBox.<method> as I ran from tkMessageBox import *